# Number of solutions so that atleast two of x,y,z are integers

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

> I have a set of equations
>   \begin{cases}x+2y+4z=9\\
> 4yz+2xz+xy=13\\
> xyz=3
> \end{cases}
>   I need to find number of solutions $(x,y,z)$ such that at least two of $x,y,z$ are integers.

I thought about trying to use the multinomial theorem to get number of non negative integral solutions to Equation $1$, but that would be for all $x,y,z$ to be integers, how do I take into account that only two of them need to be an integer? Also, how do I use the other two equations.

AM-GM probably wont help too, as that is for +ve integers. I'm just stuck, don't even know how to begin solving this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $X=x$, $Y=2y$, and $Z=4z$, then the given equations can be written as
$$
\begin{cases}X+Y+Z=9\\
YZ+XZ+XY=2\cdot 13=26\\
XYZ=8\cdot 3=24\end{cases}$$
Now note that
$$w^3-9w^2+26w-24=(w-2)(w-3)(w-4).$$
Can you take it from here?

Comment: From here I did as follows: equated each of the roots to X,Y,Z, got the respective values for x,y,z and found the number of solutions where any 2 are integers to be 5. And that's the answer!!

But could you also tell me how you got the roots of the cubic to be 2,3,4? How did you go about finding the roots?

Comment: Not only cleverly done, but you beat me to it.  +1.

Comment: @Techie5879 We have six cases: $(2,3,4)$ is equal to $(x,2y,4z), (x,4z,2y),\dots $ (all 6 permutations)

Comment: @RobertZ yes but one of them yields 2 non integer solutions for x,y,z which means I need to reject that...My question asks for atleast two of them to be integers

Comment: @Techie5879 Yes, check all the 6 cases and pick the good ones.

Comment: @RobertZ last question: how did you find out the roots of the cubic?

Comment: @Techie5879 An integer root is a divisor of $24$. Find one root (or more roots) and then divide.

Comment: @RobertZ thanks, really brilliant solution

Comment: Thanks, have a nice day!